# Problems with eval function skipping newlines in $(eval echo $myvar)

Tags: bash, pointers, eval, echo

I am currently working on a script meant to add a new project generation for any basic editor.
I am using the following structure in order to generate the right basic program (hello, world) according to the language selected by the user :

```
#!/bin/sh
#this is a short example in the case the user selected C as the language
TXTMAIN="\$TXTMAIN_C"
$TXTMAIN_C="#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    printf(\"hello, world\n\");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}"
MAIN="./main.c"
touch MAIN
echo -n "$(eval echo $TXTMAIN)" >> "$MAIN"
gedit MAIN
```

This piece of code gives the following output when you edit main.c :

```
#include <stdlib.h> #include <stdio.h> int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) { printf("hello, world\n"); return EXIT_SUCCESS; }
```

However, when replacing line 13 by echo -n "$TXTMAIN_C" >> "$MAIN", it gives the right output :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I still don't know wether that's an echo or eval issue, or if there is a way around for my pointer-like problem.
Any advice is very welcome !

Comment: Single quotes are your friend.  Much easier to write: `TXTMAIN_C='#include ... ` since you do not need to escape " or \.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few errors in your script, and it's more complicated than it should be.

If you want to use an indirect variable like that, use the `${!FOO}` syntax, and put quotes where appropriate:

```
#!/bin/sh
#this is a short example in the case the user selected C as the language
TXTMAIN=TXTMAIN_C                          # don't force a $ here
TXTMAIN_C="#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    printf(\"hello, world\n\");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}"
MAIN="./main.c"
echo "${!TXTMAIN}" > "$MAIN"                # overwrite here, if you want to 
                                            # append, use >>. `touch` is useless
```

Comment: Well, that was fast ... Thanks, you answered with exactly what I needed!